# insert into priority_queue in constructor

Tags: c++

I would like to make an object, called an Edge, which inserts itself into a priority_queue from its constructor. That is;

```
Class Edge {
   int m_from;
   int m_to;
   int m_cost;
public:
   edge(from, to, cost) : m_from(from), m_to(to), m_cost(cost) {
      edges.push(this);
}
```

The difficulty is the usual chicken-vs-egg problem. edges is a priority_queue of Edges, so it needs to know what an Edge is. Plus, it needs to have operator less-than overloaded for Edges, so that operator needs to be defined before I can instantiate the priority-queue, but it can't be defined because Edge hasn't been defined. I have tried it a bunch of different ways, but nothing works. Of course, I can just push the Edge in the code that calls the constructor,

```
edges.push(Edge(from,to,cost));
```

But it seems like there should be a way to enforce this. Basically, I am saying that these objects need to go on the priority_queue when created, so let's guarantee that happens.

Comment: Thats not undefined behavior? The object is not completely constructed when you insert it into the queue.

Comment: The explicit push() looks good enough for me. If you want to enforce it hide the priority queue and edge construction by placing both in a wrapper.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to have another class that you ask to create edges and THAT class places the edge into the collection and then hands you back a pointer. (Is this factory pattern?)

Comment: Manu343726, I see your point. Except, that would imply that "this" is never available in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
/* In .h*/

class Edge {
    int m_from;
    int m_to;
    int m_cost;
    static priority_queue<Edge*> edges;        
public:
    Edge(from, to, cost) : m_from(from), m_to(to), m_cost(cost) {
        edges.push(this);
    }
}

bool operator < (const Edge* first, const Edge* second) { return first->m_cost < second->m_cost; }

/*In .cpp */
priority_queue<Edge*> Edge::edges;
```

Comment: You will still need to overload the less than operator on edges, otherwise the priority will be based on pointer address and not cost. You should modify your answer to show this.

Comment: Nice idea, but as pippin points out, you need to overload a pointer comparison, which, it turns out, you cannot do;error: ‘bool operator<(const Edge*, const Edge*)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type    I suppose I could make a class of Edge pointers.

Comment: how about turn that priority_queue to a std::vector and sort it after the insert ?

Comment: Or you just provide your own comparator -- `priority_queue` is not limited to `operator<`!

Comment: Ferdinand - Maybe. I tried defining a Compare function, and had the same problem, i.e., chicken-vs-egg. But maybe a Compare (const Edge*, const Edge*) will work, if I declare Edge first. I'll give it a try.